# Use a button to select a random radio?

Tags: javascript, button, radio-button

I'm guessing the use of js is going to be needed, but i have a button and 4 radio's. When a user presses the 'random' button, a random radio button is to be selected.
Any suggestions welcome :)

Comment: Yes, you'd need JavaScript... what do you know about it?

Comment: Not alot at all, still trying to learn it :)

Comment: Then I recommend reading the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide), an [introduction to DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Introduction), and [quirksmode.org's articles about event handling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this HTML I made four radio buttons in the same group (radioGroup)

In Javascript I get all the buttons in the group and "check" one randomly.

```js
function callRandom() {
  var array = document.getElementsByName('radioGroup');
  var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);

  array[randomNumber].checked = true;
}
callRandom();
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Random" onclick="callRandom();"><br>
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="1"> One<br>
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="2"> Two<br>
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="3"> Three<br>
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="4"> Four
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you tell me the reason for `-1` and `+1`? It seems like they cancel each other out.

Answer (score 4):

I assume your radio is in a group, therefore will have an index in that group.

You can therefore simply use

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*4)
```

to generate the index, and there you have your radio button to select

Comment: apologies, I was in the middle of adding a fuller example when my wifi disappeared @medopal has given a perfect answer though.

Answer (score 1):

here is a jQuery version :

```
$('form :radio:eq('+Math.round(Math.random()*($('form input:radio').length-1))+')').attr('checked','checked');
```

I made a [jsFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/mica/TFNmB/](http://jsfiddle.net/mica/TFNmB/)